# How can I parse a Json file to be read in php by fgets and file_get_content?

Tags: php, json, decode, fgets

I have this sample JSON file:

```
{
"users":[
{"username":"user123","password":"123321abc"},
{"username":"user124","password":"123321abc"},
{"username":"user125","password":"123321abc"}
]
}
```

Im setting it like that becouse i need to read it in php with fgets. Like this:

```
<?php
$newUser = ["username"=>"user123","password"=>"123321abc"];
$jsonFile = fopen("JSONsample.json","r+");
while(($line = fgets($jsonFile) != false){
$oldUser = json_decode($line,true);
if($oldUser["username"] === newUser["username"]){
if($newUser["password"] === oldUSer["password"]){
doSomething($newUser);
}
}
?>
```

The thing is when `fgets` read lines that are not a complete json object it returns `null`. So it will read the first two user objects as null becouse of the comma at the end of the line. I could just erase the comma and it would return the user as I need it to. But it wouldn't be a valid JSON as a whole. I need the "users" array for other functions.

So, my question would be is there any way I can arrange my JSON so its a valid JSON file when taken as a whole and when its read line by line?

Comment: Why do you need to read it line by line instead of all at once?

Comment: Performance mostly. I imagine the Json file to get heavier than just 3 sample users.

Comment: The limitation there is memory, not processing speed. Reading it line by line is likely less efficient, it just uses less memory. Unless the file is several MB in size, I wouldn’t worry about memory usage. And beyond that I’d think about a different kind of database, perhaps SQLite if you’re trying to avoid a full database server.

Comment: Yeah, its an exercise. Im not actually doing this with and end in mind. But saw the opportunity to learn something I might not known otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure each line starts with a curly bracket '{' and ends with a curly bracket '}' in your case. Then you can assume it is a valid JSON then apply json_decode

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
   $length = strlen($needle);
   return (substr($haystack, 0, $length) === $needle);
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
   $length = strlen($needle);
   if ($length == 0) {
       return true;
   }

   return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}

$newUser = ["username"=>"user123","password"=>"123321abc"];
$jsonFile = fopen("JSONsample.json","r+");
while(($line = fgets($jsonFile) != false){
   $line = trim($line);
   if(!startswith($line,"{") || !endswith($line,"}")) continue;

   $oldUser = json_decode($line,true);
   if($oldUser["username"] === newUser["username"] && $newUser["password"] === oldUSer["password"]){
         doSomething($newUser);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats an option, but it wouldn't be performant if the json file was too big.

Comment: In that case make sure each line starts with a curly bracket '{' and ends with a curly bracket '}' in your case. Then you can assume it is a valid JSON then apply json_decode

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_file_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('JSONsample.json'), true);
$users_info = $json_file_data.users;
$newUser = $users_info[0];
$oldUser = $users_info[1];
```

I guess you can get the data from here easily, let me know if I could help ypu anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's composer packages out there that solves memory issues by parsing file streams instead of reading it all into memory, like for example the package
`salsify/json-streaming-parser`:

At Packagist:
https://packagist.org/packages/salsify/json-streaming-parser

On GitHub:
https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser